# Adding a moving average column to a table using values from previous 2 entries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I currently have the following simplified tables in my database. The points table contains rows of points awarded to each user for every bid form they have voted in.

I would like to add a column to this table that for each row, it shows the AVERAGE of the previous TWO points awarded to THAT user.

```
Users
+----+----------------------+
| id | name                 |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | Flossie Schamberger  |
|  2 | Lawson Graham        |
|  3 | Hadley Reilly        |
+----+----------------------+

Bid Forms
+----+-----------------+
| id | name            |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | Summer 2017     |
|  2 | Winter 2017     |
|  3 | Summer 2018     |
|  4 | Winter 2019     |
|  5 | Summer 2019     |
+----+-----------------+

Points
+-----+---------+--------------------+------------+------------+
| id  | user_id | leave_bid_forms_id | bid_points | date       |
+-----+---------+--------------------+------------+------------+
|   1 |       1 |                  1 |          6 | 2016-06-19 |
|   2 |       2 |                  1 |          8 | 2016-06-19 |
|   3 |       3 |                  1 |         10 | 2016-06-19 |
|   4 |       1 |                  2 |          4 | 2016-12-18 |
|   5 |       2 |                  2 |          8 | 2016-12-18 |
|   6 |       3 |                  2 |          4 | 2016-12-18 |
|   7 |       1 |                  3 |         10 | 2017-06-18 |
|   8 |       2 |                  3 |         12 | 2017-06-18 |
|   9 |       3 |                  3 |          4 | 2017-06-18 |
|  10 |       1 |                  4 |          4 | 2017-12-17 |
|  11 |       2 |                  4 |          4 | 2017-12-17 |
|  12 |       3 |                  4 |          2 | 2017-12-17 |
|  13 |       1 |                  5 |         16 | 2018-06-17 |
|  14 |       2 |                  5 |         12 | 2018-06-17 |
|  15 |       3 |                  5 |         10 | 2018-06-17 |
+-----+---------+--------------------+------------+------------+
```

For each row in the points table I would like an average_points column to be calculated like follows.

The average point column is the average of that users PREVIOUS 2 points. So for the first entry in the table for each user, the average is obviously 0 because there were no previous points awarded to them.

The previous 2 points for each user should be determined using the date column.

The table below is what I would like to have as the final output. 
For clarity, to the side of the table, I have added the calculation and numbers used to arrive at the value in the averaged_points column.

```
+-----+---------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+
| id  | user_id | leave_bid_forms_id | date       | averaged_points |
+-----+---------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+
|   1 |       1 |                  1 | 2016-06-19 |               0 |    ( 0 + 0 ) / 2 
|   2 |       2 |                  1 | 2016-06-19 |               0 |    ( 0 + 0 ) / 2 
|   3 |       3 |                  1 | 2016-06-19 |               0 |    ( 0 + 0 ) / 2 
|   4 |       1 |                  2 | 2016-12-18 |               3 |    ( 6 + 0 ) / 2 
|   5 |       2 |                  2 | 2016-12-18 |               4 |    ( 8 + 0 ) / 2 
|   6 |       3 |                  2 | 2016-12-18 |               5 |    ( 10 + 0) / 2 
|   7 |       1 |                  3 | 2017-06-18 |               5 |    ( 4 + 6 ) / 2 
|   8 |       2 |                  3 | 2017-06-18 |               8 |    ( 8 + 8 ) / 2 
|   9 |       3 |                  3 | 2017-06-18 |               7 |    ( 4 + 10) / 2 
|  10 |       1 |                  4 | 2017-12-17 |               7 |    ( 10 + 4) / 2 
|  11 |       2 |                  4 | 2017-12-17 |              10 |    ( 12 + 8) / 2 
|  12 |       3 |                  4 | 2017-12-17 |               4 |    ( 4 + 4 ) / 2 
|  13 |       1 |                  5 | 2018-06-17 |               7 |    ( 4 + 10) / 2 
|  14 |       2 |                  5 | 2018-06-17 |               8 |    ( 4 + 12) / 2  
|  15 |       3 |                  5 | 2018-06-17 |               3 |    ( 2 + 4 ) / 2 
+-----+---------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+
```

I've been trying to use subqueries to solve this issue as AVG doesn't seem to be affected by any LIMIT clause I have.

So far I have come up with

```sql
select id, user_id, leave_bid_forms_id, `date`, 
(
    SELECT
          AVG(bid_points) 
          FROM (
            Select `bid_points`
            FROM points as p2
            ORDER BY p2.date DESC
            Limit 2
                ) as thing
      ) AS average_points
from points as p1
```

This is [in this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b0ed5/1) but to be honest I'm out of my depth here.

Am I on the right path? Wondering if someone would be able to show me where I need to tweak things please!

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Using the the answer below as a basis I was able to tweak the sql to work with the tables provided in the original sqlfiddle.

I have added that to [this sqlfiddle to show it working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b0ed5/7)

The corrected sql to match the code above is

```sql
select p.*,
       IFNULL(( (coalesce(points_1, 0) + coalesce(points_2, 0)) /
         ( (points_1 is not null) + (points_2 is not null) )
       ),0) as prev_2_avg
from (select p.*,
             (select p2.bid_points
              from points p2
              where p2.user_id = p.user_id and
                    p2.date < p.date
              order by p2.date desc
              limit 1
             ) as points_1,

             (select p2.bid_points
              from points p2
              where p2.user_id = p.user_id and
                    p2.date < p.date
              order by p2.date desc
              limit 1, 1
             ) as points_2

      from points as p
     ) p;
```

Although I am about to ask another question about the best way to make this dynamic with the number of previous poingt that need to be averaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), which were introduced in MySQL 8.

```
select p.*,
       avg(points) over (partition by user_id
                         order by date
                         rows between 2 preceding and 1 preceding
                        ) as prev_2_avg
from p;
```

In earlier versions, this is a real pain, because MySQL does not support nested correlation clauses.  One method is with a separate column for each one:

```
select p.*,
       ( (coalesce(points_1, 0) + coalesce(points_2, 0)) /
         ( (points_1 is not null) + (points_2 is not null) )
       ) as prev_2_avg
from (select p.*,
             (select p2.points
              from points p2
              where p2.user_id = p.user_id and
                    p2.date < p.date
              order by p2.date desc
              limit 1
             ) as points_1,
             (select p2.points
              from points p2
              where p2.user_id = p.user_id and
                    p2.date < p.date
              order by p2.date desc
              limit 1, 1
             ) as points_2
      from p
     ) p;
```

Comment: Thank you for having a look at this! At the moment the server has only MySQL 5.7 on it and I don't see it being updated anytime soon to MySQL 8.

However - and I have tried to fix this but I am useless, I cannot make the second code sample work on my system. I continually get a "Table 'leave.p' doesn't exist" error message. 

Trying to change some of the "from p" to "from points" still hasn't resolved it. Is there a sqlfiddle I could have a look at this working!?

Thank u very much again.

Comment: Also, does this imply with mysql < 8 that if I wanted to change the number of previous points to average I would have to create a column for every one? This seems like it would be unwieldly very quickly. :(

Comment: @PilotSnipes . . . I would suggest that you ask another question with longer ranges.  This answers the question that you have asked here.  Be sure to include the number of points you want to go back.

Comment: Ok. I'll ask a new question. Thank you for putting me on the right track.